# What GLM family and link function for "proportion of time"?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, glmm, link-function

A simple question to which I don't seem to find the answer anywhere.

I have a response variable `duration of time spent doing A` of individuals tested for $\text{max duration}=X$. Therefore the variance is likely to be much wider at $x=0.5$ compared to $X=0$ and $X=1$.

However, I am confused what family and link function I need as time is continuous but can not be less than $0$ and more than $X$.

ps: I am using R so any code examples would be appreciated

**Update**
I have heard about the tobit() function from "AER" which "*is a convenience interface to 'survreg' setting different defaults and providing a more convenient interface for specification of the censoring information.*"

Therefore, it seems for my data I could run the model

`tobit(duration.A ~ factor1*factor2, left=0, right=X)`

However, it is unclear how A) I could do this for a mixed model i.e. a model with random factors, B) what it's assumptions are (they are not clear from the R documentation http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg.pdf), and C) how I could get residuals and fitted values for plotting.

Comment: Maybe look into beta regression?  Though I haven't used it and its not well integrated into glm functions in R...  Seems like gamma is a poor fit.

Comment: Thanks, that is what seems to come forward from other posts as well. However, using the betareg function I get the error "all observations must be in (0, 1)" while the range of my response is 0.000 - 1.000 and thus not 0 > x < 1.

Comment: you can also run logistic regressions with unit interval data, but obviously the whole thing about the variance being an asymmetrical function of the mean might be a poor choice.  people have also figured out estimators where the distributional form is fully data-driven, but I've never used such things.

Comment: Does an observation with the max duration as the time mean that the subject didn't finish the task in the allotted time?

Comment: No, it means an individual spent 100% of the time doing A.

Comment: Tobit might be a reasonable choice.  It is basically a latent varible model.  Look it up on wikipedia.  Random effects at the individual level can be handled, though I've only seen it done in stata (`xttobit`), not R.

Comment: The standard in economics appears to be a fractional logit model, which is just a GLM with a binomial family and logit link function, but with robust standard error. I don't know how this translates to R syntax. I have done quite a bit on beta regression, but I have recently moved to fractional logit as a more robust way of doing what a beta regression does. See: Papke, Leslie E. and Jeffrey M. Wooldridge. 1996. Econometric Methods for Fractional Response Variables with an Application to 401(k) Plan Participation Rates. *Journal of Applied Econometrics*, 11(6):619-632.

Comment: I might be tempted to consider beta regression (which isn't a GLM), but there are other choices that might in some cases work okay, such as a quasi-binomial model.